# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hibernate_sequences_pkey" exception by Postgres

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

My Spring Data (JPA/Hibernate) based application raises on increased load when persisting new entities in the Postgres the following exception: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hibernate_sequences_pkey"

The strategy for id is defined as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

I know that this strategy is not the perfect solution for Postgres, however is it the reason for the exception above?

The load is generated using Apache Camel route with splitter running inserts in parallel on multiple threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some tests it seems indeed that the problem is caused by the `strategy = GenerationType.TABLE`. With the change to `strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE` the problems described above with duplicated keys were gone.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = Consts.VEHICLE_ATTR_ID_SEQ,
        sequenceName = Consts.VEHICLE_ATTR_ID_SEQ,
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = Consts.VEHICLE_ATTR_ID_SEQ)
@Column(name = "ID", updatable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When migrating from Hibernate 4 to 5.3.1 (Wildfly 14.0.1) I also encountered the problem related to the "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hibernate_sequences_pkey" error message. After investigating the source code of Hibernate 5.3.1 I could get rid of the error using the `strategy = GenerationType.TABLE` (I also know that this strategy is not the perfect solution). The main problem was in the TableGenerator class. To solve the problem you should use in addition the GenericGenerator annotation, for example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = TableGenerator.DEF_TABLE)
@GenericGenerator(name = TableGenerator.DEF_TABLE, strategy
        = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator", parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = TableGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEGMENT_PER_ENTITY, value = "true")})
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;
```

setting the `TableGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEGMENT_PER_ENTITY` parameter to the true value (as it has false value by default and in this case Hibernate will use the "default" segment name in hibernate_sequences table instead of table names).
You also should set the `hibernate.model.generator_name_as_sequence_name` property to a false value to have only one hibernate_sequences table otherwise, Hibernate will use generator names as names for sequence tables (according to https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/9a75fa8d979185b6014a814bf3ffd09e32143939#diff-936141a440957cd8a9c4a93a744e92a0 changes). In additional (but not necessary) you can set `hibernate.id.generator.stored_last_used` property to a false value as well (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/9af565510064635dba7e48087ab4e8f5ef439f0d changes) because:

> In order to be compliant with JPA specifications, the value stored by
>   Hibernate 5.3 in the Table used by the
>   `javax.persistence.TableGenerator` is the last value generated.
>   Previous versions of Hibernate instead stored the next value to be
>   used.
>
> For backward compatibility a new setting,
>   `hibernate.id.generator.stored_last_used`, has been introduced that
>   gives the opportunity to fall back to the old Hibernate behaviour.
>   Existing applications migrating to 5.3 and using @TableGenerator have
>   to set `hibernate.id.generator.stored_last_used` to `false`